# Android Simulator Not Responding

Tags: android, simulator

I'm using eclipse and have the android plugin. I made a simulator that is running 1.6. I'm trying to run the demo app that it comes with and it freezes on me and I have to end the process. I never get it to run the demo. Anyone have some advice?

Demo App Code:

```
package com.demo.DemoApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

My Output:

```
[2011-06-29 15:31:32 - DemoApp] ------------------------------
[2011-06-29 15:31:32 - DemoApp] Android Launch!
[2011-06-29 15:31:32 - DemoApp] adb is running normally.
[2011-06-29 15:31:32 - DemoApp] Performing com.demo.DemoApp.MainActivity activity launch
[2011-06-29 15:31:32 - DemoApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Test-Device-1.6'
[2011-06-29 15:31:32 - DemoApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Test-Device-1.6'
[2011-06-29 15:31:41 - DemoApp] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-06-29 15:31:41 - DemoApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-06-29 15:32:29 - DemoApp] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.demo.DemoApp.MainActivity activity launch'!
```

Comment: Is there any output in ADB?  Also what demo app?  Does it freeze before or after you try to launch the app?

Comment: Start the emulator and wait for it to fully load. It takes some time. Then run your app.

Comment: Hi Chris! I updated the post with the demo app code and the output I get in eclipse. it freezes once I see the simulator on the screen. It shows "Android_" and the underscore flashes for about 30 sec and then crashes.

Comment: @Spidy How do you start the emulator before the app runs? Sorry I think I've been calling the emulator the simulator the whole time. Whoops!

Comment: The emulator takes ages to start. (the honeycomb emulator takes up to 5 mins on my Phenom II 955 Quad with 8 gb ram ...)  Make sure to check "Snapshot enabled" in the AVDs settings. Once the emulator has started it saved its state to your disk. From this point on it starts faster when restoring from that.

Comment: Eclipse->Window->Android SDK and AVD Manager. Virtual Devices->Emulator->Start

Comment: Ok I just checked the Snapshot enabled and now I started the emulator and it's not responding again. the title bar says Test-Device 1.6 (Not Responding) like anything else in windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a solution for your particular problem, but i gave up on the simulator, is just to cumbersome and slow. Get a real device, your life will improve greatly. They are fairly cheap right now. Trust me, the simulator is just not worth your patience.

Comment: I have a droidx2 but I don't want to debug on a physical device in case I code something that could break the phone.

Comment: You can't broke your phone from java since it runs on a virtual machine. You better start with the sdk documentation to get some concepts clear from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Wipe user data on the simulator to start it from scratch.  That usually resolves this problem for me.

Comment: Tried that as well and still did the same thing. Could it be a hardware issue?

Answer (score 1):

The android default emulators are very slow. You can use any real device or Gennymotion in your system. Gennymotion simulators have better performance than the default ones.

Comment: You just responded to a question that is four years old! They didn't have Intel x86 emulation back then, nor did they have genymotion. ;-) In any case, welcome to StackOverflow! This is a good answer and a good first post, even if it's a tad bit late.